# How can we access super class's method which a sub class has overidden? Hows that possibly on memory level?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I saw an example where a super class's original method was accessed from the subclass's method which is an overridden method. But a sub class's instance will only have a method that's an overridden method and not the superclass's method.But how come subclass is able to access super class's method.

[Reference which says an sub class instance has only overiden method](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dg7bj_e-SAMC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=java+override+method+jvm+implementation&source=bl&ots=39lu5igGD5&sig=hC1Ph8tvT0oocLc5biz6AfaFmFg&hl=en&ei=fyHPSqq4M4WL4QavpLyEAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q&f=false)

```
// A Java program to demonstrate that overridden  
// method can be called from sub-class 

// Base Class 
class Parent 
{ 
    void show() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Parent's show()"); 
    } 
} 

// Inherited class 
class Child extends Parent 
{ 
    // This method overrides show() of Parent 
    @Override
    void show() 
    { 
        super.show(); 
        System.out.println("Child's show()"); 
    } 
} 

// Driver class 
class Main 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Parent obj = new Child(); 
        obj.show(); 
    } 
} 

OUTPUT:
Parent's show()
Child's show()
```

Comment: Do you mean "why is this supported?" or "how do I do it?"

Comment: Parent obj = new Child();
obj.show();

it is calling show() which is a instance of Child, in childs show() it is calling super.show() which is a Parent instance's show(). even if u override in childs that is only applicable to child.as u r calling super.show() abviously it will print parent's show right!

Comment: @chrylis It is supported. But how does that happen. How is that possible if a subclass instance has only overidden method as mentioned in the link.

Comment: or Just tell me what is super in memory level.

Answer (score -1):

A class probably has a table of function pointers to its implementation methods. It probably has a reference (implicit by class layout or explicit via a pointer or some sort of reference) to its super class and has indirectly access to that class's table of function pointers. All these are implementation details not specified in the Java language.

An analogy can be found http://www.faq3.de/OrganizeMe/pg/pdf/inside.the.c++.object.model.pdf on page 93

Calling super.show() logically moves to the super class's (Parent) table of function pointers and calls that class's show() method.

Comment: The OP is specifically asking for the implementation details, and this answer only provides guesswork. This would be better as a comment.

Comment: @Bobulous It can only be guesswork as this is not specified in Java. Implementations are free to do this any way. see: docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/…. The OP is trying to figure out how the class gains access to the super class method. This can only be done by keeping a reference (implicit or explicit) to the super class. I have updated my answer to add these points.